# upgraded to AppCompat v7 support library but do not want to use it's actionBar

Tags: android, android-layout

after I upgraded the following code does not work:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActionBar()
                .getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

it returns a null pointer. The solution is to use getSupportActionbar(), but i don't want to use that... I to use the same actionbar it was using before the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend from AppCompatActivity, you will always get null from getActionBar().

If you want ActionBar from getActionBar() extend your activity directly from Activity and not from AppCompatActivity.